# Kotlin coroutines UI not freezing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I've checking the livedata coroutines lately and i get to something i cannot understand. why is this code (When observed) not freezing the UI?

```
    val lv =
    liveData (context=Dispatchers.Main){
        var x = 0
        while (true){
            emit(x++)
            delay(1000)
            println(Thread.currentThread().name)
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`delay` doesn't block the thread. It just suspends your coroutine and resumes it after one second. You can change `delay` to `Thread.sleep(1000)` and your UI will be frozen because `Thread.sleep` will block the thread.